# Extract data using index, not name

Tags: php, arrays

I am parsing a csv file, and then looping it like so.

```
foreach ($this->csvData as $dataKey => &$item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        print_r($item);
    }
}
```

Now if I output item, I can see something like the following

```
array:12 [
  "ID" => "12345"
  "CODE" => "AZ6G"
  "YEAR" => "2009"
  "WEEK" => "13"
  "FULL_DATE" => "29/04/2014"
  "SALES" => "asdas89.34"
  "QUANTITY" => "3"
]
```

So the above example represents one row in the csv, the key is the header name and then it has a value.

The problem is this, I know which columns I need to keep based on an index value.  These values are selected by the user at a previous stage.  So in the above example I know I need to keep the ID, FULL_DATE and SALES, so in my database I have 0, 4, 5 which represents their indexes.

Now I need to extract these columns. If I do something like the following

```
foreach ($this->csvData as $dataKey => &$item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        print_r($item[4]);
    }
}
```

I will get an undefined index problem as there is no key named 4. If I give it the name of the key, it will work, and show me the value.

So how can I get the value using the key index instead of the name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and then loop over those `keys` you said you get from the Database like so:

```
<?php

$keys = [0, 4, 5];
$data = [
  "ID" => "12345",
  "CODE" => "AZ6G",
  "YEAR" => "2009",
  "WEEK" => "13",
  "FULL_DATE" => "29/04/2014",
  "SALES" => "asdas89.34",
  "QUANTITY" => "3"
];

foreach($keys as $key) {
    echo $data[array_keys($data)[$key]] . "\n";
}

//  outputs:
//  12345
//  29/04/2014
//  asdas89.34
```

Explanation what happens:

```
array_keys($data)[0]; // is "ID"
// and the "ID" can be used as "key" for the $data array with
$data[array_keys($data)[0]]; // which is $data["ID"]; => "12345"
```

You can play with it online here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d6a4d86a6cdceccf4034fca06dcef9e50a89dc8